# Too broad questions,Really too broad or just my questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderators

I have some time not to be active in the community, an hour ago I asked a question and only after the user ( StephenG ) accused my question of being too broad was closed, I want to compare my question with another question from a new user.

My question : [Time travel : Reproduction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112830/time-travel-reproduction)

New user question :[Why might a computer want to play God](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112826/why-might-a-computer-want-to-play-god)

As you can see both questions are on hold,Both have little details,But guess what? The moderators didnt close his question instantly unlike mine.

This power-trip behaviour is very discouraging and im losing my hard earned reputation,And i dont like wasting my time and energy,To be honest im still here because i cant delete my account with all my questions,I really like worldbuilding but this power abuse is not user friendly,This site expects too much but offers too little now,Is not fun,Is not productive and this hyper moderation is pointless.It helps nobody.

I have nothing against the other user,Is just a comparision,Is my question really too broad? If yes,Why the moderators didnt close the other one instantly unlike my question?

And yet im still here,Because i want to exchange and share ideas and emotions with other people around this little and boring world that we call earth and have fun in the process.

Good night to everyone,Im not in mood to keep writing for now.

-Myrmidon.

Comment: Both questions were closed about 20 minutes before you posted this meta question - the other two and a half hours before it was posted, and yours an hour and 15 minutes after it was posted. That's not really quick, and it's not a large difference; it's probably just due to the fluctuation in user traffic at those points in time.

Comment: No moderators have been involved in these two closures. Mods have a diamond next to their name. Like HDE above. The others are just normal users with enough reputation to put questions on hold.

Comment: Closing a question does not reduce reputation. Reputation is lost to downvotes (and a question being closed may actually save it from getting more downvotes!)

Comment: Isn't calling out individual users in meta posts a violation of the Be Nice policy, or something?

Answer (score 1):

> Is my question really too broad? If yes,Why the moderators didnt close the other one instantly unlike my question?

Yes, it's too broad

Moderators didn't close your question at all, so that part is invalid.

Comment: But they did, in a sense: Everyone here is a moderator to some degree ;) ♦ moderators had nothing to do with it, but they are not the only ones here responsible for moderation. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: @Mołot the OP didn't mean that, I'm answering their question, not nitpicking a new question out of thin air.

Comment: I am puzzled. How can a question that has precisely one outcome be too broad? Particularly since that outcome can be described both briefly & succinctly.